# When and why do I need to change a window coordinate to a canvas coordinate?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I tried to see the difference between a window coordinate and a canvas coordinate by giving a canvas a callback that prints the coordinates of a mouse click in both types. I expected the two types of coordinates to have different values, but they didn't. Also, I tried to pass window coordinates to the `find_closest` method which, as stated in the [documentation](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_closest-method), accepts canvas coordinates, and there was no error.

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    print()
    print("Window x-coordinate:", event.x)
    print("Window y-coordinate:", event.y)
    x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    print("Canvas x-coordinate:", x)
    print("Canvas y-coordinate:", y)
    print("closest:", canvas.find_closest(x, y))

master = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(master, width=50, height=50, bd=5, bg="green", relief="groove")
frame.pack_propagate(0)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(frame)
button.pack(fill="none")

canvas = tk.Canvas(master, bd=5, width=50, height=50, bg="red", relief="ridge")
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
canvas.pack_propagate(0)
canvas.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to do the conversion if your canvas is able to scroll. Otherwise there's a 1:1 mapping between window and canvas coordinates.

You can see this by adding the following code to your example, at some point after creating the canvas:

```
canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,1000,1000))
canvas.yview_moveto(.5)
canvas.xview_moveto(.5)
```

There's also another behavior that is not commonly used, which is that `canvasx` and `canvasy` can round the coordinate to the size of a `gridspacing` unit.

Here's the [canonical description](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M30) of the `canvasx` method:

> Given a window x-coordinate in the canvas *screenx*, this command returns the canvas x-coordinate that is displayed at that location. If *gridspacing* is specified, then the canvas coordinate is rounded to the nearest multiple of *gridspacing* units.

You can observe that by changing your calls to `canvasx` and `canvasy` to be something like the following, which will return coordinates that are always a multiple of 2.

```
x = canvas.canvasx(event.x, gridspacing=2)
y = canvas.canvasy(event.y, gridspacing=2)
```